# How to take a decision based on the result of jquery form form validator

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

On click of a Save Button i am doing form validation using jquery.validate.min.js

I want to do an ajax call if and only if validation is passed or else i dont want to continue execution

This is my code

HTML:

```
<form id="myform">
 <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" class="icon-user" /> 
<a href="#" class="savedata">Save</a> 
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: {
                required: 'name required'
            }
        }
    });
});

$(document).on("click", ".savedata", function (e) {
    $('#myform').valid();
    alert('doing an ajax call here ');
});
```

Could you please tell me how to put a if condition for this ??

Comment: It would be `if ($('#myform').valid()) { ...`  However, you don't need a `click` handler with `valid`.  You simply need to put your `ajax` within the `submitHandler` option.

Comment: The answer by Banana contains the solution.  However note, that despite its wording, the `invalidHandler` is **not needed**.

Answer (score 0):

as stated on the plugin's website: [jQuery Validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/), you need 2 callbacks:

**submitHandler** -  to implement your own form submit, eg. via Ajax.
**invalidHandler** - to react when an invalid form is submitted.

```
$(".selector").validate({
    invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
        //show message that form is invalid
    },
    submitHandler: function () {
        //submit form using ajax
    }
});
```

Comment: The `invalidHandler` option is irrelevant to this answer.  By default, the plugin will show the error messages next to each invalid item without it.

Comment: @Sparky you are right, i just wanted to add the option for a custom error message if he wants in the future. invalidHandler is irrelevant here but not redundant :)

Comment: There is so much confusion with how to properly use this plugin, that I wanted it to be crystal clear to the reader that the `invalidHandler` has nothing to do with anything when the user wants to implement `ajax` within the `submitHandler`.  At that rate, you might as well have mentioned all the other plugin options too.

Comment: @Sparky woa someone got up on the wrong foot today... chill man its not like redefined jQuery for him

Comment: Have it your way then.

Comment: @Sparky yes thank you for the honest downvote, because my answer definitely did not answer OP's question.

Comment: I tried giving you rational and honest feedback to make the answer less confusing to the newbies.  _"you need 2 callbacks"_ ~  No, you don't...  `submitHandler` is the only thing that's needed to answer the question.

Comment: @Sparky im not going to argue with you, have a nice day.

Comment: What argument?  You're making a claim that the `invalidHandler is "needed".  That is factually false and you agreed with me in your comment... _"invalidHandler is irrelevant here"_.  It cannot be "irrelevant" while it's "needed".  I'll happily remove my vote if you fix the wording.